# How to delete a column in all dataframes that exist within a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I  have 52 `dataframes` within a list. They all have the following variables: Week   region   value

I want every `dataframe` to only have 2 columns (being region and value). How can I remove the week from every `dataframe`.

The `dataframes` are called `LIST1$HeatAcc2011Week1`, `LIST1$HeatAcc2011Week2`, `LIST1$HeatAcc2011Week3`, etc all the way up to 52.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` from the purrr package and `select` from the dplyr package.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

LIST1 <- map(LIST1, select, -Week)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `lapply`:

```r
LIST1 <- lapply(LIST1, function(x) x[,c("region","value")])
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is `setdiff`

```
lapply(LIST1,  function(x) x[setdiff(names(x), "Week")])
```

Or assign to `NULL`

```
lapply(LIST1, function(x) `[<-`(x, 'Week', value = NULL))
```